# Codeigniter 404 error page, routing issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have uploaded my web project using codeigniter on the server godaddy and I can access it thru this link http://izhi-ks.org/facelajm/blog

I have bought a new domain www.facelajm.com for this site, and I have updated the directory to /facelajm and I get 404 Page Not Found error.

so my ftp looks like this:

in the root I have another site which is joomla and within that dir I ahave a folder called **facelajm**.

In the codeigniter root dir i have a .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What I am doing wrong, that I cant open the site only by typing www.facelajm.com
In fact it does if i only create a new index.php and print hello world...
I am doubting on the htaccess or maybe config file?

here is config.php as well:

```
$config['base_url'] = "";

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Have you updated the name server records for the domain? How does your host handle multiple domains? Virtual hosts? This sounds like a question for Server Fault, rather than Stack Overflow...

Comment: Why when I create an index.php with hello world it does open it in the root of codeigniter files??? I am doubting more on the routing maybe smth wrong i have :s, from the hosting side, I just have setup the domain to the /facelajm directory as the supporter said

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your `.htaccess` in the `facelajm` directory (which should be the root of your domain) to the following. I think you forgot to turn on `RewriteEngine` and forgot to set `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**Update**

A default controller needs to be set in `routes.php`

```php
$route['default_controller'] = 'blog';
```

Comment: how could I make working only by facelajm.com without need of writing /blog

Comment: Have you defined a Default Controller in `routes.php` http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#default

Answer (score 4):

If you using Codeigniter V3, check the first letter of your controller is in upper case, example:

```
 ci/application/controllers/dealer/Api.php
```

Comment: Me too, had to go through my models and controllers and remove all caps except the first letter. Will try later to figure out why, just happy its solved right now :)

Answer (score 1):

update your `config` file

```
/* your base url or your domain name for your application*/
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com"; 

/*For your default index page generally this is empty */
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I migrated to a new environment and it started showing 404 on all subpages. I had to edit Apache's httpd.conf, replacing all instances of **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All** (lines 231 and 268 in my case). Reloaded Apache and it worked fine without any further changes.